Publicación de API creada en .NET Core 8
Estoy experimentando dificultades al intentar publicar una API. Anteriormente, ya había publicado una API y, en esa ocasión, el proceso se realizó sin inconvenientes. Todo funcionó correctamente una vez que se configuró en IIS. Sin embargo, al intentar volver a publicar la API con los cambios recientes, no se están reflejando en la implementación; solo se reconocen los cambios anteriores, mientras que los nuevos no son considerados. No comprendo qué pudo haber sucedido, ya que en teoría estoy utilizando el mismo perfil de publicación. Espero poder encontrar una solución a este problema.
Gracias por atención y espero tengan un buen día

¿Has detenido el servicio, el app pool? ¿Has eliminado todos los datos de la carpeta donde publicaste antes de colocar los nuevos archivos? Por cierto, bienvenido a SOes, recuerda realizar el recorrido para formular buenas preguntas, del mismo modo obtienes tu primera medalla y evitas que te cierren preguntas mal hechas, toda una ganga estar informado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Saludos :D

gracias por responder, no borre el perfil de publicacion, asi como tampoco elimine ningun archivo los archivos, pero cuando quise publicar haciendo un  nuevo perfil me di cuenta que ese perfil me publica mucho menos archivos, mientras el primer perfil me arroja todas las bibliotecas y archivo que uso, este nuevo solo me arroja una cantidas pequeña, mas que nada unos archivos .json, un ejecutable y unos dll

Un gusto colaborar. Edita tu pregunta y agrega todos los pasos que has realizado junto con todo lo que has obtenido, entre más detalles, mejores chances tienes de conseguir buenas respuestas, asimismo, evitamos jugar a los detectives y vamos de frente a la solución y/o posible solución de tu caso. Saludos :D
